# select option value based on value of custom attribute?

Tags: jquery

How do I select a `select` option based on a variable value.

```
var getVal = 'a3';
```

Using a variable like this. How would I select the option `Val 3`

```
<div class="id_100">
  <select>
    <option customID='a1' value="vala">Val 1</option>
    <option customID='a2' value="valb">Val 2</option>
    <option customID='a3' value="valc">Val 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I know that if I use this:

> ```
>  $(function() {
>      $("div.id_100 select").val("valc");
>  });
> ```

then I can select a option based on the `value`, but how do you select a `option` based on the `customID`?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/9Stxb/610/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it by using [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$("div.id_100 select").val( $("div.id_100 select option[customID=a3]").val() );
```

updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Stxb/611/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".id_100 select option[customID='"+getVal+"']");
```

Comment: There is no variable of `a3`.

Comment: sorry.i forgot to add variable